# Wordpress site not displaying correctly after changing host

Tags: wordpress

I have moved a WordPress site to a new host by copying the `public_html` folder and importing the database. I have updated the name-servers for the domain. The address is www.casavulturului.com. I have changed the wp-config and I generated a new .htaccess and my site now displays an older version of it and so losing part of the work I've done to it. I have flushed the dns and deleted the cache. I don't see where the problem is. Please help.

Comment: Have you read and followed http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress? That is the #1 resource on the topic

Comment: Yes I have read and done as it says...

Comment: If the data you see is old, almost the only explanation is that you're working with an old data dump. Are you 1000% sure it's an up to date database file?

Comment: maybe your hosts file is pointing the domain to the old location

Comment: I spoke with someone who said I should wait until it gets all propagated, altough I don't see why since the info is in the DB. I will try to redownload the db and import. However, since yesterday, there have been changes on the site without me doing anyting...

Comment: Issue solved. Updated Database. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed by itself aft6er a couple days. Seems it didn't have time to refresh